# Why is this PDE semi linear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Could someone tell me why is this PDE semi-linear ?

$a_{1,1}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+a_{1,2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y }+ a_{2,1}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=f(x,y)\cdot u$, where $a_{i,j}$ are constants.

According to the definition of semi-linear, the above equation shouldn't be semi linear but quasi linear since the degree of the partial derivatives is 2.

**Definitions:**

Semi linear if the PDE is of the form $f(x_1,\dots,x_n,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},\dots)$

Quasi linear if the PDE depends on $f(x_1,\dots,x_n,u,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial x_i},\dots)$

Comment: That's a linear equation.

Comment: really? My professor told us it was semi linear